# Add-on menu doesn't get created when published through G-Suite Marketplace SDK, but does through Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, menu, google-forms, google-apps-script-addon

Whether by using createAddonMenu() or createMenu(), I can't create menu when add-on is installed through GSM, or when opened with "Integrate With Google" via G-Suite Marketplace SDK. "Test as add-on" via Script Editor works, installation via Chrome Web Store works, and I have no idea what might be wrong. I'm not sure if the script runs in the first place.

I've tried existing solutions from StackOverflow such as calling functions in different order, but nothing seems to work.

Does someone know what might prevent add-on/script from working with GSM?

Here's onOpen and onInstall functions I used.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  if(LOGENAB){console.log("onOpen...");}
  if(LOGENAB){console.log(e.authMode);}
  if(e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE){
    // Authorization needed
    if(LOGENAB){console.log("# Authorization required!");}
    var ui = FormApp.getUi();
    var menu = ui.createMenu('title');
    menu.addItem('Authorize', 'authorizeAddon');
    menu.addToUi();
  } else {
    // Authorization not needed
    if(LOGENAB){console.log("# Authorization OK!");}
    var ui = FormApp.getUi();
    var menu = ui.createMenu('title');
   menu.addItem('Control Panel', 'showControlPanel');
   menu.addItem('About', 'showAbout');
   menu.addItem('Reset running status','toggleStatus');
   menu.addToUi();
  }
}
function onInstall(e) {
  if(LOGENAB){console.log("onInstall...");}
  onOpen(e);
}
```

Comment: Add the execution transcript and the errors on executions failures from https://script.google.com

Comment: I'd wrap all the code in your `onOpen()` function in a `try/catch` and in the catch block use `console.error('Error on open ' + e)` which will log an error to Stackdriver.  The user doesn't need to authorize any permissions in order to use `console.error()`    It looks like you are using a global variable named `LOGENAB`  Global variables can cause `onOpen()` to fail.  I wouldn't use the onOpen function to test for authorization status, or to try to display different menus.  I would just build the regular menu.  What authorization issue are you trying to deal with?

Comment: When using a global variable, don't assign a value to the global variable in the global space.  You can define global variables, and not assign a value to them in the global space, and then assign a value to them by running a function.  If you assign a value to a global variable in the global space, it will cause an error which will stop your onOpen() function from running.  If the add-on was installed, but the user canceled the authorization, then the add-on could end up being installed but not authorized.  But when the user does something they should be prompted automatically to authorize.

Comment: @AlanWells I tried these, but nothing works. The GSM version just won't work. Seems like onOpen and onInstall are never called in the first place. I removed all other code from those, and replaced it with "console.error()". Nothing shows up in Stackdriver logs.

Comment: All I can do is guess, but maybe it has something to do with how the Google Cloud Project is configured.  The scopes must be defined in TWO places, 1) the GSuite Marketplace SDK *and* 2) APIs and Services -> Credentials -> OAuth consent screen.  Plus, if you need to avoid using restricted scopes, you will need to configure scopes in the appsscript.json file.  Unfortunately, we will probably never get an answer from Google about what the true problem is, so that leaves "trial and error" until it hopefully starts working.

Comment: @AlanWells Scopes are configured and consent screen is verified. GSM SDK is enabled as instructed in documentation. I'm completely clueless with this as well. It just won't work.

Comment: It might be a bug, but documenting the steps to reproduce the problem could be time consuming.  You'd need to create a new Apps Script file, start with very basic, simple code that does nothing but creating a menu.  If that works, then add files and code back in, and keep re-publishing until the menu didn't show up.  Then you'd know what code was causing the problem, because it would be the last code added.  But, that could take a long time to do, and it still might not find the problem if it's an issue with the Marketplace.

Comment: If you started with very basic, stripped down code and still had the problem, then I'd say it was something with the publishing process and not your code.  If it's something with the publishing process, then it's obviously out of our control, unless there is some trick to making the settings just right.  The add-on publishing system is in transition currently from the Chrome Web Store to the GSuite Marketplace, so Google may not have all the problems worked out yet.

Comment: @AlanWells Indeed, they have the transition going on. I tested with new GCP project with `onOpen`, `onInstall` and `testfunction` (~10 lines of code), and same problem happened: nothing shows up, UI or logs.

Comment: Here is the official google email address to give feedback on the OAuth review process: oauth-feedback@google.com  I would inform them about the issue. 
 That email address was originally posted in the Google group at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-apps-script-community/feedback%7Csort:date/google-apps-script-community/95vZ6BIjIe4/hhVbBlf7AAAJ

Comment: Does the code work without the if(LOGENAB) condition?https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/menus: "Warning: If you attempt to take actions that require authorization when the authorization mode is ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE, it results in an error. This may prevent your add-on menus from being displayed.", "add-ons must create an initial menu before the add-on is authorized by the user" and "Add a menu item based on properties (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE)". More useful information: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#authorization_modes

Comment: @ziganotschka This shouldn't be the problem. I've already tried solution where all global variables were replaced with local. No success. And as said, only G-Suite Marketplace & G-Suite Marketplace SDK has this "doesn't even seem to run it" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add-ons published as unlisted didn't show up in editor with older version of G-Suite services when installed through GSM. This appears to be fixed in current version of the service.